# How to block everything except whatsapp?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, fritzbox, whatsapp

I'd like to block access to the internet on my smartphone for everything except whatsapp.

I could do this on a fritzBox or on DD-WRT routers.

Any advice?

Comment: **ADD MORE INFO**. Block only one or all devices? Home or office? PC or smartphones?

Comment: Also, do you just need whatsapp chat, or also video/voice calling?

Comment: Smartphones at home, and I just need chat to be available - I'd block video/voice, but that's a nice to have.

Comment: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Restrictions. If the control plane of dd-wrt is like the Linksys then under Restrictions there is an option to block/allow specific application. This is how it looks like in [LinkSys](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-to-manage-your-kids-internet-use-with-your-router/)